# image size in jssor jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am using Jssor slideshow from http://www.jssor.com/

My slide container is 720px width X 300px height

but some of the images are larger while some of the images are smaller.

I want to know how can I change the maximum size of images larger than 720X300 but leave the image size as it is for images smaller than 720X300?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option, the closest way is to set $FillMode to actual size.

Comment: I think there is an option, $FillMode 5 which says (contain for large image, actual size for small image)

I believe thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

add this to your img element:

```
style="max-width:100%"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an option, $FillMode 5 which says (contain for large image, actual size for small image) I believe thats what you are looking for